# Add required input pattern to variables inside if

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, input

I have the following if that, so far, the only thing it does is to not let it trigger the form ajax submission if any input is blank. Being empty is one of the conditions but besides that, I'd also like it to prevent the form from being sent if a required filling pattern for each field is not respected. I've tried some things but they didn't work, so I guess I'm probably making mistakes regarding the synthax or other details. What would be the best way to do it?

```
(function($){

   $('#enquiry').submit( function(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      var fname = $.trim($('.fname').val());
      var lname = $.trim($('.lname').val());
      var email = $.trim($('.email').val());
      var subject = $.trim($('.subject').val());
      var message = $.trim($('.message').val());

      if (fname === '' || lname === '' || email === '' || subject === '' || message === ''){
        alert('trigger error message')
     }
     else{
        alert('ajax call sending the data')
}
```

Here's the form code, in case it's relevant:

```
<form id="enquiry" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
  <div class="form">
     <input class="input fname" placeholder="a" name="fname" type="text" autocomplete='off' pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,36}" required></input>
     <label for="namef" class="">Your name</label>
  </div>

 <div class="form">
     <input class="input lname" placeholder="a" name="lname" type="text" autocomplete='off' pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,36}" required></input>
     <label for="surname" class="">Your surname</label>
 </div>

 <div class="form">
     <input class="input email" placeholder="a" name="email" type="text" autocomplete='off' pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" required></input>
     <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
 </div>

 <div class="form custom-select">
     <select class="input subject" name="subject" autocomplete='off' required>
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
       <option>Option 3</option>
     </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form2">
     <textarea class="input message" placeholder="a" name="message" autocomplete='off' pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z- ]" required></textarea>
      <label for="tellme" class="">Tell me something</label>
 </div>
  <div class="contactbutton">
     <button type="submit" class="button" role="button"><span>SUBMIT</span></button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried to test for a "*required filling pattern*"? And please post a complete example, including the code of the form and the whole event handler and the definition of all these variables.

Comment: `[fname, lname, email, subject, message].includes('')`

Comment: I've added the form code and other details, I hope it's clearer now! What I'd need is that the `if` perform a check with the same "pattern" parameters I'm using in the input elements inside the form div.

Comment: @matheusrvdc Oh, that! Then you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation

Comment: I've checked it better and it seems to work! I've set up the if like this: `(!fname.validity.valid || !lname.validity.valid || !email.validity.valid || !message.validity.valid) ` , do you think it's a good approach?